let $ξ,ζ∈ℂ$, prove $\frac{(ξ+ζ)^n-ξ^n}{ζ}-nξ^{n-1}=ζ\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{kζ^{k-1}(ξ+ζ)^{n-k-1}}$ for $n\geq2$

let $ξ,ζ∈ℂ$, prove $\frac{(ξ+ζ)^n-ξ^n}{ζ}-nξ^{n-1}=ζ\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{kζ^{k-1}(ξ+ζ)^{n-k-1}}$ for $n\geq2$

This is an intermediate step for a theorem I'm proving (Theorem 1.16 here)
It's true for $n=2$; checking, one can see that
$\frac{(ξ+ζ)^2-ξ^2}{ζ}-2ξ=\frac{ξ^2+2ξζ+ζ^2-ξ^2}{ζ}-2ξ=\frac{2ξζ+ζ^2}{ζ}-2ξ=2ξ+ζ-2ξ=ζ$, and also that
$ζ\sum_{k=1}^{1}{kζ^{k-1}(ξ+ζ)^{1-k}}=ζ(1)(1)(1)=ζ$
So, the statment to be used as the inducuctive hypothesis for this theorem is: $\frac{(ξ+ζ)^i-ξ^i}{ζ}-iξ^{i-1}=ζ\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}{kζ^{k-1}(ξ+ζ)^{i-k-1}}$ for $n\geq2$
Proving for $i+1$:
$\begin{align*}\frac{(ξ+ζ)^{i+1}-ξ^{i+1}}{ζ}-(i+1)ξ^{i} &= \frac{(ξ+ζ)^i(ξ+ζ)-ξ^iξ}{ζ}-iξ^{i}-ξ^{i}=\frac{(ξ+ζ)^i}{ζ}(ξ+ζ)-\frac{ξ^i}{ζ}ξ-iξ^i-ξ^i\\
&=\color{red}{ξ\frac{(ξ+ζ)^i}{ζ}}+\frac{(ξ+ζ)^i}{ζ}ζ\color{red}{-\frac{ξ^i}{ζ}ξ-iξξ^{i-1}}-ξ^i\\&=ξ\color{red}{(\frac{(ξ+ζ)^i-ξ^i}{ζ}-iξ^{i-1})}+(ξ+ζ)^i-ξ^i\\&
=ξ\color{red}{ζ\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}{kζ^{k-1}(ξ+ζ)^{i-k-1}}}+(ξ+ζ)^i-ξ^i\end{align*}$
This is where I get stuck, any ideas on what to do next, or if there's something wrong? I don't see how to arrive to $ζ\sum_{k=1}^{i}{kζ^{k-1}(ξ+ζ)^{i-k}}$

It's slightly eaiser to prove the equivalent statement:
$$(a+b)^n = a^n + na^{n-1}b +  b^2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k a^{k-1} (a+b)^{n-k-1}.$$
Assuming it is true for some $i$,  multiplying by $(a+b)$, we get
$$(a+b)^{i+1} = a^i(a+b) + ia^{i-1}b(a+b) +  b^2 \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} k a^{k-1} (a+b)^{i-k}.$$
On the other hand, we want to show that
$$(a+b)^{i+1} = a^{i+1} + (i+1)a^{i}b +  b^2 \sum_{k=1}^{i} k a^{k-1} (a+b)^{i-k}.$$
Since $ a^i(a+b) + ia^{i-1}b(a+b) = a^{i+1} + (i+1)a^i b + ia^{i-1}b^2 $, when we add on the common term of $b^2 \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} k a^{k-1} (a+b)^{i-k}$, we conclude that the two expressions are equivalent.
